# preg_replace {varying text}

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a regex expression for preg_replace($the_expression, "", $old_text)

I have text like:

{some text} Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only {varying text} five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s {some other text}with the release of Letraset sheets containing

I want to target any varying text inside curly brackets, and the curly brackets too, and replace with "" (nothing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex that you're looking for is something like this:

```
{[^}]+}
```

Which matches:

```
{     - A left curly brace
[^}]+ - Anything that is not a right curly brace, one or more times
}     - A right curly brace
```

So, in [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace), it would be:

```
$new_text = preg_replace( '/{[^}]+}/', '', $old_text);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a non-greedy regex:

```
$new_text = preg_replace( '/{.*?}/', '', $old_text);
```

Comment: What is non-greedy regex? Thank you

Comment: Normally, `*` and `+` in a regex matches as much as it can, so if you use `{.*}` on the string `foo {thing1} bar {thing2} baz`, it will match `{thing1} bar {thing2}`; this is called "greedy". If you want it to match the shortest possible substring, you put `?` after the `+` or `*`. `{.*?}` just matches `{thing1}`.